# .removeAttribute in Javascript fails

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to remove the id from all `<td>` that are named "date[]", because if i keep the id, a jquery datepicker messes up later.

the following function is used to remove the id

`document.getElementsByName('date[]').removeAttribute('id');`

Firebug tells me:
TypeError: document.getElementsByName(...).removeAttribute is not a function

I tried all combinations of `'` and `"`, and also just `date` instead of `date[]`.
I don't think its a typo, because i copied this from w3schools

Comment: does `document.getElementsByName('date[]')` return a collection of DOM nodes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`document.getElementsByName` returns a collection, you have to iterate and remove:

```
var collection = document.getElementsByName('date[]');
for (var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
    collection[i].removeAttribute('id');
}
```